# Laravel calling a method on a user if not logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a method in my User model that is:

```
public function hasRole($roles)
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($role === $this->role_id) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And I am adding a class to the body of my app by checking this methods return:

```
<div id="spark-app" v-cloak class="{{ ( Auth::user()->hasRole([1]) ? 'customer' : '' ) }}">
```

This correctly works, but if there is no logged in user I of course receive an error.

```
Call to a member function hasRole() on null
```

Is there a way to still use this shorthand statement along with checking if there is a user?

I could wrap the shorthand in an inline if statement but it feels messy. Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: you could make a helper method on the controller, and check if isset(Auth::user()) first, before checking if it hasRole. And then on the blade just call your method

Answer (score 6):

Laravel provides a method to check if the user is logged in, which is `Auth::check()` (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)).

```
<div id="spark-app" v-cloak class="{{ ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole([1]) ? 'customer' : '' ) }}">
```

Comment: This is the right solution, please include the link to the documentation if possible: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

Comment: I initially tried that but faced the same error. Turns out I was was also calling hasRole in another location so have solved it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="spark-app" v-cloak class="{{ ( null !== Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole([1]) ? 'customer' : '' ) }}">
```

**EDIT**: @AntoineB's solution is definitely cleaner.